# When I buy PC Minecraft at Gamestop, do I get a code to get Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I buy Minecraft for the PC at Gamestop, do I get a code to enter into Minecraft.net to get a Minecraft account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get a gift card that you can use as the payment method when buying a Minecraft account.

If you have any more questions, ask the seller.